# Cross-Browser Compatibility Issue With FireFox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Trying to attain a **near-exact** cross-browser experience for our clients, lately, I've come to a problem that I can't fix. I've got the website up and running, and it's functioning smoothly on every and each browser, expect **Mozilla Firefox**. The problem that occurs in Firefox, is that I get to witness a broad white space on the right side of the site's main contents, and it is arising from my responsive css3 slider. The link below shows you 100% of the slider's codes, which works perfectly on jsfiddle;

[Css Slider](https://jsfiddle.net/59cj3m9n/)

but well, the problem is that each `article` tag is taking its space, even when it's hidden and not being displayed in **Mozilla**. So the more the slider comes toward the end of it, the less white space I get to see. The next upcoming slides are hidden, but however, they are still occupying a certain space, which forces a lot of vacuous area on the right side.

[image]

You can check the website itself at the link below;

[My Website](http://cakevamp.com/main/index.html)

Hoping that I have clearly stated the issue, what could be the possible solution for this matter ?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding overflow-x: hidden on the <html> tag seems to fix it. I'm not sure why, though. Hopefully someone has a better solution.

Comment: <html> tag - thanks for pointing out it was missing from the answer

Comment: Well, the solution provided is actually very neat, all I did were adding overflow-x:hidden to the body tag, and boom, the vacuous area is gone. Thank you @libertyernie ....